# mktextfm error: failed to make TFM file

Tags: fonts

I've just installed `texlive-full` AUR package (version 2023.20230620) on my Manjaro Gnome Vulcan 23.1.0 computer.
When I try to compile previously downloaded (and working) complicated latex project the compiler runs `mktextfm` font utility:
`mktextfm larm1440`
and I get an error message like this:

```
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)
(Fatal base file error; I'm stymied)
grep: larm1440.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input larm1440' failed to make larm1440.tfm.
```

I've googled for a several hours to find out the origin of this problem with no result.
What may cause this error? What should I do to resolve it?

If additional information concerning my system or tex package or this latex project is needed I gonna provide it of course

Comment: It would probably be better if you provided a small but full document that gives this error. I have TL23 installed and there are no larm font files found. So what exactly are you doing here to trigger this?

Comment: Exactly where? I have the full installation and should not be missing anything from CTAN.

Comment: Thanks, daleif. I assume "larm" font files correspond to Cyrillic symbols.
I found "larm" files within these folders:
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lh/lh-t2a/larm.htf
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/5/lh/lh-t2a/larm.htf
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/koi/8r/lh/lh-t2a/larm.htf
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/win/1251/lh/lh-t2a/larm.htf

I assume these files are parts or "lh" package

Comment: and note that is for tex4ht (and engine that converts to html). You mention no where that you are using `tex4ht`

Comment: hmm I really don't use tex4ht

Comment: the exception forwards me to the "fontenc.sty" file and its 112th string:
\usefont\encodingdefault\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault

Comment: As mentioned at the start make a minimal example others can test on their systems to see if they get the same result. Thus guessing game gets us nowhere.

Comment: daleif, as i mentioned in the question body, the project is complicated and consists of many files so i cannot represent you a minimal working example of the file producing the error. But I can send you a link to download a full project as a zip archive:

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/NpvWbanQJpr-7w

The main file of this project is "dissertation.tex"

Answer (score 0):

`Fatal base file error; I'm stymied` indicates your mf installation is broken. Ask your distro. I replied with a few more details on the mailing list.

The larm* mf sources are dynamically generated, which is why they do not exist in the TL sources. For example, I get:

```
mf '\mode:=ljfour; input larm1440'
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)
kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1440
mf: /u/karl/.texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a/larm1440.mf: successfully generated.
(/u/karl/.texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a/larm1440.mf
...
Font metrics written on larm1440.tfm.
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking part!
Could this happen due to some path settings?
One of advises what I found during googling told to look the command ```kpsepath mf |sed -e 's/:/\n/g'``` output. My output looks like this:

Comment: ```~
.

/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/2023/texmf-config/metafont//

/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/2023/texmf-var/metafont//

/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/texmf/metafont//

!!/opt/texlive/texmf-local/metafont//

!!/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-config/metafont//

!!/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-var/metafont//

!!/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/metafont//

/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/2023/texmf-config/fonts/source//

/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/source//

/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/texmf/fonts/source//

!!/opt/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source//

```

Comment: ```~
!!/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-config/fonts/source//
!!/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/source//
!!/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/source//
/home/dmitry/.config/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/source//
```
I'm sorry for return symbols absence.
It's clearly visible that all the folders within /opt/ directory start with "!!" symbols. I assume it's somewhat like comments making these strings unavailable

Comment: The !! is not a comment. It means "only use the ls-R file, don't ever look on the disk." (I wrote some comments in the texmf.cnf file to explain syntax.)

Comment: The error message `(Fatal base file error; I'm stymied)` means mf is finding the file `mf.base`, thus it's not a path problem. The problem is that the mf.base file is not generated for the same version of mf. Ultimately this is, as I said, a distro problem. You may be able to work around by removing the mf.base file(s) on your system; mf can be configured to automatically remake them. Run `kpsewhich --all --engine=/ mf.base` to find the files (or use `locate`, if you have that set up).

Comment: Well. According to the fact I use Arch User Repository ```texlive-full``` package within my Manjaro system and this package is Arch-community-maintained I'm gonna ask ```texlive-full``` AUR package maintainer for support